# Laravel: automatically casting URL query parameter

Tags: laravel

Heyho,
I'd like to know, if it is possible to automatically cast url parameters (ideally by using the validation rules).
So the best example is just a bool:

```
https://somewhereintheinter.net/?thebool=false
```

The first thing would be, that the Validator would fail. You can fix that by either changing the `validateBoolean()` or using your own Rule.

But then, because query parameters are cast into strings, `"false" == true`... `filter_var()` converts that well, but there doesn't seem to be any ways of fixing that and axios for example does exactly that to booleans.
Even though I'd generally consider tailoring your api to your front-end application bad practice, casting a `string "false"` into a `bool false` - if the parameter is intended to be a boolean - does feel reasonable. At least if your medium stringifies everything.
Of couse you could cast everything with `prepareForValidation()`, but the Formrequest already knows what it expects, soo... is there a way, without drilling into the dephs?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. The query string as the name suggests is a string.  There's no way to differentiate between `thebool=false&thestring=false` when you want one to be a bool and the other to remain as a string so there's no automatic way to convert them all conversions need to be done manually.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't simply send `?thebool=1` or `?thebool=0`? When casting on Laravel, `(bool)'1'` and `(bool)'0'` results in the correct values `true` and `false`. Also, your JS front end _should_ properly convert something like `data: { thebool: true }` to `?thebool=1` as a Query String (or POST body, etc.)

Comment: @aokryfos" When you add a rule 'boolean' to the validator of the Form request - The system got the information, that the parameter should be a bool -> so if it is castable by filter_var(), then it should cast it. I want to know if there is an easy way to do so.

@TimLewis: well, like I said: axios doesn't - but axios is one of - if not the - biggest http client lib for javascript, so... I don't have the time to pick this fight.

Comment: I didn't mean to pick a fight or anything btw; I'm in the same boat as apokryfos in that I don't see an easy way of automatically handling this. I'm honestly surprised `axios` doesn't do that conversion; I thought for sure that it did . If it doesn't, you can do `{ data: { thebool: 0 }` (or `1`) and have it work still. Is that an option?

Comment: I meant a "fight" with axios, exactly about the "why don't you convert that?"-topic.
And there at least is the way of writing my own Formrequest-class and searching through the rules to find the boolean parameters and converting them automatically in this class. But that is what I would consider 'drilling'. So I hope to find a more intuitive way.
Fixing this in the front-end would mean all projects always need this extra layer between application and axios, that converts booleans into ints and I'd prefere beeing able to use the "vanilla"-axios.